# Как нарисованную картинку вывести в ImageView?

Tags: java, android

Рисую так:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, w, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawARGB(1, 178, 229, 255);
    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setStrokeWidth(1);
    canvas.drawCircle(400, 400, 100, p);
```

Есть компонент:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
```

Как теперь нарисованное отобразить на экране в компоненте ImageView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого есть метод `ImageView#setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)`. В вашем случае:

```
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Также надо убедиться, что при создании `Bitmap` её ширина заметна (т.е не 0 или 1 etc), что и было причиной проблемы в данном конкретном случае

Comment: нашел ошибку, размеры Bitmap указал неправильно.

Comment: Попробуйте ещё вот это добавить: `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);`

Comment: И проверьте что у вас `w` не 0

Comment: В этом и была ошибка (w=1).

Comment: А как задать масштабирование картинки (пальцами по экрану)?

Comment: @kaaa, добавил в ответ про размеры. Масштабирование можно по разному. Не очень понятно что именно вы под этим имеете в виду, но, думаю, может помочь либа `PhotoView` https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: Либу посмотрю, спасибо. Я имел ввиду увеличить или уменьшить изображение (мультитач вроде называется) без применения сторонних библиотек.